# Html String with LATEX not rendering properly in webview flutter

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, webview, mathjax

I am using **webview_flutter: ^4.2.2** to render HTML Strings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax example</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
  \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

above is the HTML Code with the **LATEX** embedded in it.

It should show the required result which it is showing after running the above code snippet.

But it rendering the above code like this

When (a \ne 0), there are two solutions to (ax^2 + bx + c = 0) and they are [x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.]

this is because it is not loading the **javascript scripts** inside the html.

Why Webview is not loading the scripts?

Please help??